# DateListPlot not showing any ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks

With a vector `dates` (in DateList format), and a vector `data` that has the same length as `dates` and contains numerical values,

```
DateListPlot[{dates, data} // Transpose]
```

produces a very nice plot with automatically spaced time or date stamps. Today for some reason, I am getting a framed plot with no ticks or indices.

This has started happening after I restarted Mathematica after a crash.

Comment: Check the output of `Options[DateListPlot]` and make sure they match the defaults listed in the docs.

Comment: Yes they do. I've also tried including `Ticks -> True` and `FrameTicks -> True`. No luck.

Comment: Okay, please post your OS and version to help with diagnosis.

Comment: Mathematica 10.1 for Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the behavior you describe:

[image]

by going into the **Evaluation** menu, and deselecting **Dynamic Updating Enabled**. If you make sure this is selected, you should get ticks for `DateListPlot`. You may need to slightly resize existing graphics for them to show up, or reopen the notebook.

---

`DateListPlot` uses the *func* case of the `Ticks` specification, so the ticks get computed on the fly once the plot range has been determined by the frontend. That function evaluation is actually using the same mechanism as `Dynamic` to have the kernel compute the ticks, even though `Dynamic` isn't literally present in the output anywhere.