# Frame ticks disappear in LogPlot and LogLogPlot -- Bug in Mathematica 12.1?

Tags: plotting, ticks, logarithmic-scale

I have this code here:

```
Plot[1/x, {x, 1, 10}, Axes -> True, Frame -> True]
```

It generates this output, as intended:

[image]

So far so good. But now I want to switch to a log plot. This is the code:

```
LogPlot[1/x, {x, 1, 10}, Axes -> True, Frame -> True]
```

This is the output, and the frame ticks disappeared!

[image]

The same happens for a log-log plot. Can anyody reproduce this? Why are the ticks gone?

Comment: It works fine on 12.1.1.0 (Windows 10).

Comment: Works as expected with both v12.1.0 and v12.1.1 on a Mac

Comment: Please read the [tag:bugs] description. There should be a community consensus to tag a question as a bug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateListPlot not showing any ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84537/datelistplot-not-showing-any-ticks). I believe this issue is fixed in 12.1.

Comment: I updated to 12.1 and the issue is still there. Moreover, changing the "Dynamic Updating" from Enabled to Disabled and vice versa does not do anything. The problem persists. Also: how is my post a duplicate? I did not find any similar problem and working solution, and believe me, I have searched.